# Is there a way to arrange for a nerd dinner meetup through SO?

Tags: discussion, community, meetups

With the level of personal details given by SO users...is there a way to query them (by say location) and ping/invite the resultant people for nerd-dinner like event?

Comment: Seems like anyone involved enough in SO to be interested in a meetup probably already reads meta, so you might just need to post here.

Answer (score 5):

April 6, 2011 will be World-Wide Stack Overflow MeetUp Day per [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/). Organization of specific events is being left up to individual users.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could do this.

There is already a data dump [query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/128/users-by-location-with-a-minimum-reputation) to find users by location with a minimum reputation (and [here](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/162/list-of-users-in-a-given-location) is the version without the minimum reputation parameter).

You'd have to comment-ping everyone to invite them.

<sub>Hey, I didn't say it would be easy. :)</sub>

Comment: Wow, I never knew we had people that lived in central kentucky, thought it was too... country.

Comment: @Lord and I assume the same with Oklahoma?

Comment: ...I just found out I'm the top SO user in my state. The person right underneath me is "j0rd4n" which strangely enough is my first name. I don't even know what to think.

Comment: Phew... I actually used this technique for the StackO 2012 Aberdeen Meetup! Thanks @Jon!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about *announce*, but it *might* be appropriate to create a room on [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com) to discuss logistics etc.