# How to announce a meetup?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to arrange for a nerd dinner meetup through SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60494/is-there-a-way-to-arrange-for-a-nerd-dinner-meetup-through-so)

Now, I have arranged for mmetup of SO users...is there a way to brodcast/announce it in SO?